# Recursive Binary Search Function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, binary-search, tail-recursion

```
int binarySearch(int a[], int low, int high, int x) 
{ 
    if (high >= low) { 
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; 
  
        if (a[mid] == x) 
            return mid; 
  
        if (a[mid] > x) 
            return binarySearch(a, low, mid - 1, x); 
  
        return binarySearch(a, mid + 1, high, x); 
    } 

    return -1; 
}
```

Is the above Binary Search Algorithm tail-recursive? Why? If no, then why not?

Comment: Binary search does not need additional space for performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, it *is* tail recursive. It doesn't do anything with the results of each of its recursive calls, except directly returning those results right away.

This means you could replace it with a loop which would update the `low` and `high` variables while looping until the stopping condition is met. The `a` and `x` variables stay the same right now, so they wouldn't be changed in the loop based version either.

Comment: it all depends on the compiler in use, but it *can* be.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer depens on what you mean by tail-recursive. Do you mean the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) or do you mean "will my compiler implement this without recursive `call`s"?
A compiler might recognise recursive patterns that are not technically recursive and still roll them into a loop.

In your case, it's easy to check by just [looking at the assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/MoK6be), which indeed shows that no `call`s are present and recursion has been turned into a number of jumps.

```
binarySearch(int*, int, int, int):
.L9:
        cmp     esi, edx
        jg      .L7
.L2:
        mov     eax, edx
        sub     eax, esi
        sar     eax
        add     eax, esi
        movsx   r8, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi+r8*4], ecx
        je      .L1
        jle     .L4
        lea     edx, [rax-1]
        cmp     edx, esi
        jge     .L2
.L7:
        mov     eax, -1
.L1:
        ret
.L4:
        lea     esi, [rax+1]
        jmp     .L9
```

Comment: TR is a well-defined concept. whether a given compiler will perform TCO for a TR code or not, is a separate issue.

Comment: @WillNess Which is exactly my point. "Is this function TR" is not equivalent to "will my compiler emit iterative code". I believe OP asked for the latter, but I can't be sure.

Comment: well, I read their question *literally*, so, the former. :) unfortunately they are not staying engaged here.

Comment: @WillNess Given that your post provides the correct answer for the former, all bases should be covered :)